# WebView Android

Tags: android, html, webview

**Добрый день!**

У меня возникла на редкость "удивительная" проблема при работе с WebView. Дело в том, что я использую кэш, и когда отсутствует доступ к интернету, все грузится оттуда. **Инициализация кэширования во вью:**

```
wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY) ;
if( Constants.IS_NET_AVAILABLE )
{
    wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(100*1024*1024*8);
    String cachePath =
         context.getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    wv.getSettings().setAppCachePath(cachePath);
    wv.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    wv.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE);
}

    wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    wv.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("UTF-8");
```

Все изображения, а в частности, бэкграунды в HTML-сущностях грузятся лишь каждый второй раз! Т.е, запускаю я, предположим, новую активность в WebView - все прекрасно работает. Перезапускаю - все картинки( бэкгроунды ) не грузятся!

**В чем же тут дело? Спасибо!**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я не специалист, но кажется вместо `WebSettings.LOAD_NO_CACHE` нужно использовать `WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ELSE_NETWORK`

Answer (score 0):

Поставь код в onCreate() должно всегда срабатывать!

Comment: Во-первых, код и так там, а во-вторых, метод onCreate() срабатывает только во время запуска активности( т.е за все время жизненного цикла метод будет вызван лишь однажды - в самом начале ). Дело тут совсем не в этом, к тому же..